# Need Some Clarification on Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Recently I came upon some code on a Python tutorial for recursion, it is a basic factorial recursion:

```
def factorial(n):
print("factorial has been called with n = " + str(n))
if n == 1:
    return 1
else:
    res = n * factorial(n-1)
    print("intermediate result for ", n, " * factorial(" ,n-1, "): ",res)
    return res  
print(factorial(5))
```

This is the console output:

```
factorial has been called with n = 5
factorial has been called with n = 4
factorial has been called with n = 3
factorial has been called with n = 2
factorial has been called with n = 1
intermediate result for  2  * factorial( 1 ):  2
intermediate result for  3  * factorial( 2 ):  6
intermediate result for  4  * factorial( 3 ):  24
intermediate result for  5  * factorial( 4 ):  120
120
```

After doing some research, I feel like I have an understanding of why this is the output but I wanted to make sure. From my understanding:

it repeats the else statement 4 times and puts the n value and res value into a call stack. When res calls factorial(1), it goes to the base case and stops the recursion so we can retrieve the stack data. It pops n =1 and doesn't print any output, but then pops 2,3,4,5 and retrieves their res values that were calculated during recursion. Finally once res is returned enough, we are left with 5*24(n*res) on the top of the stack and Python knows that's the value to return for the print(factorial(5)).

Is this all correct information, am I missing something? Please let me know if any of this is incorrect or point me in a direction of some resources that can clarify this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

Notice how `factorial(n-1)` is called before

```
print("intermediate result for ", n, " * factorial(" ,n-1, "): ",res)
```

That's why you first get the `"factorial has been called"` print messages before the`"intermediate result" prints.